# Scope of exported variable in express and jade

Tags: node.js, express, scope, client-side, pug

I'm having a few issues with Jade and scope of variables exported from the route. This might be an obvious answer, but my googling abilities have failed me.

In my route, I have this code :

```
res.render('index', {title: "App",
                     csvData: json  // This is a json object
};
```

In my view, I want to display the length of the json object on the click of a button. My jade looks like this :

```
extends layout
block content
  script
    -var test123 = csvData;
    -console.log(test123.length);
  div 
    button.btnCSV(onclick='console.log(test123)') Save As CSV
```

The first console.log prints the correct length, but when I do press the button, it tells me that test123 is undefined. I think this has something to do with the difference between client side/server side variables. If that is the case, is there anyway to make a server side variable accessible to a client side scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how your example would work with the script content prefixed with a -, this indicates unbuffered code.  JavaScript that runs server side and that produces no direct output, so your in-line script is most likely empty.

Similarly your onclick handler is just compiling a string on the server, which is the main problem you appear to report.

In order to achieve what you trying to do, you should define a function in the script block which can be called from your buttons onclick handler.  Take care to ensure that your script keyword ends with a . so that the following lines are treated as block content of the script.

Here's what your template should look like.

```
extends layout
block content
  script.
    var test123 = !{JSON.stringify(csvData)};
    function printLength() { 
      console.log(test123.length);
    }
  div 
    button.btnCSV(onclick='printLength()') Save As CSV
```

Then on the server side make sure you're returning an actual JavaScript object, or an Array, and not a string representation... it should look like this

```
res.render('index', {title: "App",
                     csvData: [{ val1: 'value1', val2: 'value2' }]  
};
```

This allows variables to be used for server side scripting (if required) as well as client side.

Comment: My object is generated dynamically, how can I achieve the second part of your answer ?

Comment: Do you mean your object is a string? JSON.parse(string)

Comment: I committed a cardinal sin: ask a question before trying it out. It works fine. 

Thanks for the help.